# “beide” vs. “beides” and “alle” vs. “alles”

Tags: adjective, pronoun, adverb

I was asked when to use *beide* and when to use *beides* as well as *alle* vs. *alles*.

Here are two examples:

> Tee oder Kaffee? Ich mag **beide** Getränke.  Egal, ich trinke **beides**.
>
> Ich habe **alle** Übungen gemacht. Ich habe **alles** gemacht.

I think the reason is that in the first example the words are adjectives and in the second sentence they are adverbs, but I’m not sure.

Comment: http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-all3.html, http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-beide.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first case in your examples uses the pronoun *attributively*, i.e. it inflects like an adjective. That means that you have no choice: it has to be "beide Getränke", because that's what the inflection rules say.

The second case uses *substituting* pronouns. You can use "beides" because that's the most general form, which can substitute for everything, whether masculine, feminine or neuter. But you can also parse it as a (very common) elliptical construction: "beide" is understood as short for "beide (Getränke)" if that term was used previously, and that's why "beide" is *also* correct in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

That's not very difficult:

> alle = *all*
>
> alles = *everything*

Same goes with *beide*. In English there is only one word for that: *both*, but in German you can transfer the rule.

However, you **could** use *alle* and *beide* without a noun, if the context is clear (then it's an *ellipis*):

> Welche Getränke trinkst du? - Ich trinke beide. (=Ich trinke beide [Getränke])
>
> Hast du die Hausaufgaben? - Ja, ich habe alle gemacht. (=alle [Hausaufgaben]).

If you still have difficulties understanding when to use which, take a look at [this discussion about *viel/Vieles* and *wenig/Weniges*](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/viel-vieles-wenig-weniges.41735/?hl=de)